# Why the difference in this opinion between Mishnah berurah and Aruch hashulchan?

Tags: shacharis-morning-prayer, mishnah-berurah, korbanos-ketores-prayers, aruch-hashulchan, orach-chaim

With regard to reciting Korbanos in particular parshas Tamid, MB states that it should be recited with understanding of halachos of Tamid as a offering, Aruch hashulchan says its more recited as a tefillah and doesn't require understanding to recite it. If one doesn't understand the halachos of Tamid, it's better not to recite it? Why do they differ in its purpose and condition on reciting it?

Comment: Where do they say these things?

Comment: @Double AA The Mishnah Berurah writes (Orach Chayim 48:1) that this means “studying in order to understand the details involved in the sacrifice and not merely saying the words.” Without understanding what the Hebrew words mean, a person does not receive the zechut of being deemed as if he brought a sacrifice. There is no reward for merely reciting korbanot."

Comment: @Double AA The Aruch Hashulchan, however, takes a different approach. He states (Orach Chayim 48:1) that “whenever the relevant passages are read, it is deemed as if a sacrifice was brought.” At no point does he even suggest that it is necessary to study or comprehend the meaning of the sacrificial passages.

Comment: @Niel interesting question, thanks for the contribution. I think it would be helpful if you were to include the two quotes within the body of your question. It is generally encouraged to cite your sources and post them if possible. It makes your question more accessible and is more likely to generate quality answers.

Comment: @ Deuteronomy Ashaynem dank for the tip. I'm still new on here and learning the ropes of what does and doesn't work. Ashaynem dank for the advice i will do better.